# Binary Partial Writing Error

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

The code directly below attempts to send a message through a Java websocket; however, it occasionally produces the error (shown in the error stack below). Could anyone suggest what the problem'solution?

Code:

```
  if(currSession != null && currSession.isOpen()) {
          try {
               currSession.sendMessage(new BinaryMessage(flowTable.getBytes()));
              } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Error Stack:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The remote endpoint was in state [BINARY_PARTIAL_WRITING] which is an invalid state for called method
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase$StateMachine.checkState(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:1015)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase$StateMachine.binaryPartialStart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:963)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialBytes(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:140)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendBinary(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:56)
                at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.sendBinaryMessage(StandardWebSocketSession.java:202)
                at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.sendMessage(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:107)
                at com.hp.fucms.impl.TopoRestController.setFlowTable(TopoRestController.java:147)
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your code in a synchronized method and funnel all calls through this new method. It appears the tomcat web socket cannot handle multiple messages being placed on the same websocket session at the same time. I have code which has been running flawlessly under Glassfish and fell apart instantly when I moved to Tomcat. I then altered my code as explained above and all my problems went away....and there was much rejoicing.

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks a ton. Hopefully you get checked for the answer at some point.